# Iterate through a pandas dataframe to send data to the database in batch of 100,000 records instead of date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to iterate through pandas dataframe but currently I am filtering based on column 'DATE'. Basically, this data is pretty big and each date contains around 50K records which takes around 40 minutes to insert the data in the database. I am trying to move from this approach and try to iterate through the dataframe and send 100,000 records at a time until every record from the dataframe is uploaded in the database. This is what I have done so far but not sure how to iterate to take 100,000 records at a time.

Please don't tell me to use chunksize (commented already in the code). It was way too slower and I had to use fast_executemany=True instead.

```
for f in hours['DATE'].unique():
    hours.loc[hours['DATE'] == f]
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print(f)

    print('Time Starts: ', datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    
    # Variable names
    Server='server'
    Database='db'
    Driver='SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
    Database_Con = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + Server + '/' + Database + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=' + Driver
    
    
    # Creating an engine connection 
    engine=create_engine(Database_Con, fast_executemany=True)
    engine = engine.connect()
    
    
    hours.loc[hours['DATE'] ==f].to_sql('KRONOS_EMPLOYEE_HOURS_TEMP',
                      engine,
                      schema='dbo',
                      #chunksize=math.floor(2000/len(employee_roster.columns)), # this works along with method='multi'
                      #chunksize=100000,
                      ##method='multi',
                      if_exists='append',
                      index=False
                      )
    
    print('Time Ends: ', datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: `chunksize=` and `fast_executemany=True` are not mutually exclusive. With `fast_executemany=True` enabled, `.to_sql(…, chunksize=2)` will create multiple `.executemany()` batches of 2 rows each, and pyodbc will use the `fast_executemany=True` mechanisms to send them to the server.

Comment: I tried that before but it decreased the performance that's why I did not use chunk size.

Comment: "Decreased the performance" compared to what?

Comment: I mean it terms of time. With chunksize enabled, it took more or less 20 minutes and when I removed it then it took around 4 minutes to insert the data. You may be right in someway but I am wondering if I can just loop through the dataframe and send batches that way. Any thoughts?

Comment: So with `fast_executemany=True` and `chunksize=100_000` it took ~20 minutes, and with `fast_executemany=True` and `chunksize=None` it took ~4 minutes?

Comment: Right. I am not sure about the logic behind though.

Comment: How many rows, in total, in the DataFrame?

Comment: In the other dataframe it was about 2 million rows. In this one, I have almost 80 million rows.

Comment: You might try [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) with `chunksize_100_000, method=mssql_insert_json` and see if that does any better.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge fastexecute_many will vary in performance depending on your driver. If all else fails you could try building your own 'bulk' inset query

Comment: `fast_executemany=True` can also get bogged down under certain circumstances if the [parameter values contain None](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741). That's why I suggested an alternative using OPENJSON in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve what you want by either using SQLAlchemy's ORM Session functionality, or running this in a counting for loop. The ORM functionality is better, since you start a session, then add all the records you want to insert, then commit the changes, which the session manages. As far as I'm aware there isn't a limit to the number of records you can insert at once (I looked through the SQLAlchemy documentation and can't see any mention of this). Considering SQLAlchemy is designed to be driver agnostic (the same code should interface with SQLite, PostgreSQL, ODBC, MySQL, Oracle, etc), and each driver has different insert limitations, I imagine that the session automatically flushes in batches of *x* records, where *x* is the insertion limit for the given driver. The ORM works pretty well, so I'll give some sample code that might be useful for you, but I'll also provide some code for a counting for loop you can put your code in.

### ORM Solution

The principle is that you set up a class (inherited from `declarative_base`) that holds your table information. This also provides a readable structure for you creating record inserts. As you'll see, each class attribute is a `Column()`, with the constructor arguments holding what would be the SQL typing and keywords. After that, you create an engine like you already have, then use `sessionmaker` to make a session. After that, you can run a for loop, iterating through your pandas dataframe row by row, running the `Session.add(record)` method for the constructed record. Once all records are added, you can simply `Session.commit()` to run the query. For me, the code inserts a dataset of 75k+ lines in about 8 secs to SQLite (which has an insertion limit of 1000), or 24 seconds to an Azure hosted remote PostgreSQL database. There are probably ways to optimise this, but it does at least work, and would be a marked improvement over 40 mins (like how?). Additionally, as you can see, you can massively increase processing this by converting from a pandas dataframe to a numpy array (see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-iterating-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-7dd5f9992c01))

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    Text,
    DateTime,
    Float)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Employees(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblEmployees"
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(Text)

class Hours(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblHours"
    id  = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    datetime = Column(DateTime)
    hours = Column(Float)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tblEmployees.id'), nullable=False)
    

# Variable names
Server='server'
Database='db'
Driver='SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
Database_Con = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + Server + '/' + Database + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=' + Driver

engine = create_engine(Database_Con, fast_executemany=True)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
s = Session()
t = time()
print('Time Starts: ', datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
try:
    n = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for x in n:
        record = Hours(**{
            'datetime'    : x[0],
            'hours'       : x[1],
            'employee_id' : x[2]
        })
        s.add(record)
    s.commit()
except Exception as e:
    s.rollback()
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}][WARNING] Error inserting rows to database.")
    print(f"[INFO] {e}")
finally:
    s.close()
print(f"Time elapsed: {str(time()-t)}s.")
print('Time Ends: ', datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

### Counting Loop Solution

Ok, so for this, simply create 2 variables, `i` and `sqlLimit`. The latter is a constant you set at whatever you want (like 99,999 since 0 is counted, giving 100,000 records), and the first gets updated during execution. You create a for loop to iterate through each row of the pandas dataframe, then run a check inside: if `i == sqlLimit` or `i == len(df)`, then run the sql, reset `i = 0`, start new sql, add row; otherwise increase `i` and add row.

```
i = 0
sqlLimit = 99999
for x in range(len(df)): #where df is your dataframe
    if i == sqlLimit or i == len(df):
        # sql execution
        if i == len(df):
            break
        else:
            i = 0
            sql = "" # or whatever to set it to what it was at the beginning of the loop
            # add formatted row to sql (with .iloc?)
    else:
        i += 1
        # add formatted row to sql (with .iloc?)
```